# ActionScrip3 get specific child from multiple nested containers

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to ask you for help with Actionscript 3. How to get access to one from two children (titleBannerPicture in concrete) call from function TitleBannerEffects() (parent is titleBannerContainer sprite object). Classical approach like titleBannerContainer.titleBannerPicture or this.titleBannerContainer.titleBannerPicture or this.titleBannerPicture return error or undefined status. This syntax works only in constructor TitleBanner() function. Please can someone help me with this banal problem.

Thank you.

Sample of code:

```
package myscript {
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.BitmapData
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.filters.BitmapFilterQuality;
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;
import Math;

public dynamic
class TitleBanner extends Sprite {
    // Premenne nastavania objektu
        public var pictureName_str: String = "Title_Banner_Picture";
        public var maskName_str: String = "Title_Banner_Mask";
    // Premenne tlacitok
        public var buttonActivation: Boolean = true;
    // Premenne efektu zmeny obrazku
        private var actualPicturePosition: String = "LeftUp";
        private var nextPicturePosition: String = "RightUp";
        private var titleBannerMaskWidth: Number;
        private var titleBannerMaskHeight: Number;

    // Konstruktor
    public function TitleBanner(): void {
        // Nacitanie Container-u
            var titleBannerContainer: Sprite = new Sprite();
            titleBannerContainer.name = "titleBannerContainer";
            this.addChild(titleBannerContainer);
        // Nacitanie masky do Container-u: titleBannerContainer
            var titleBannerMask_mc: Title_Banner_Mask = new Title_Banner_Mask();
            titleBannerMask_mc.name = "titleBannerMask_mc";
            titleBannerContainer.addChild(titleBannerMask_mc);
        // Nacitanie obrazku do Container-u: titleBannerContainer
            var titleBannerPicture: Bitmap = new Bitmap(new Title_Banner_Picture());
            titleBannerPicture.name = "titleBannerPicture";
            titleBannerContainer.addChild(titleBannerPicture);
        // Priradenie masky
            titleBannerPicture.mask = titleBannerMask_mc;
        // Nastavenie filtrov Container-u
            titleBannerContainer.filters = TitleBannerFilters();
        // Nastavenie efektu posuvania obrazkov
            titleBannerMaskWidth = Math.ceil(titleBannerMask_mc.width);
            titleBannerMaskHeight = Math.ceil(titleBannerMask_mc.height);   
            TitleBannerEffects();  
    }
    private function TitleBannerFilters(): Array {
        // Nastavenie Glow efektu
            var titleBannerGlowEffect: GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
        //titleBannerGlowEffect.alpha = 1;          
            titleBannerGlowEffect.color = 0xffffff;
            titleBannerGlowEffect.blurX = 20;
            titleBannerGlowEffect.blurY = 20;
            titleBannerGlowEffect.inner = true;
            titleBannerGlowEffect.strength = 2;
            titleBannerGlowEffect.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
        // Nastavenie Shadow efektu
            var titleBannerShadowEffect: DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter();
            titleBannerShadowEffect.alpha = 1;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.color = 0x666666;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.blurX = 4;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.blurY = 4;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.inner = true;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.angle = 45;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.distance = 4;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.strength = 1;
            titleBannerShadowEffect.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
        // Navratova premenna
            return [titleBannerGlowEffect, titleBannerShadowEffect];
    }
    private function TitleBannerEffects(): void {
        switch (actualPicturePosition) {
            // Prechod prveho obrazku
                case "LeftUp":
                    switch (nextPicturePosition) {
                        case "RightUp":
                            trace("LeftUp -> RightUp");
                            //trace(this.getChildAt(0).name].numChildren);                  
                        break;
                        case "LeftDown":
                            trace("LeftUp -> LeftDown");
                            break;
                        case "RightDown":
                            trace("LeftUp -> RightDown");
                            break;
                        default:
                            trace("No transition");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            // Prechod druheho obrazku
                case "RightUp":
                    switch (nextPicturePosition) {
                        case "LeftDown":
                            trace("RightUp -> LeftDown");
                            break;
                        case "RightDown":
                            trace("RightUp -> RightDown");
                            break;
                        case "LeftUp":
                            trace("RightUp -> LeftUp");
                            break;
                        default:
                            trace("No transition");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            // Prechod tretieho obrazku
                case "LeftDown":
                    switch (nextPicturePosition) {
                        case "RightDown":
                            trace("LeftDown -> RightDown");
                            break;
                        case "LeftUp":
                            trace("LeftDown -> LeftUp");
                        break;
                        case "RightUp":
                            trace("LeftDown -> RightUp");
                            break;
                        default:
                            trace("No transition");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            // Prechod stvrteho obrazku
                case "RightDown":
                    switch (nextPicturePosition) {
                        case "LeftUp":
                            trace("RightDown -> LeftUp");
                            break;
                        case "RightUp":
                            trace("RightDown -> RightUp");
                            break;
                        case "LeftDown":
                            trace("RightDown -> LeftDown");
                            break;
                        default:
                            trace("No transition");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want to access titleBannerContainer or its children from outside of the constructor that variable needs to be made a property of the document class. You are declaring the variable inside the constructor, so it will only exist inside the constructor. To make that variable a property of the document class, put the variable declaration outside of the constructor, like this:

```
class TitleBanner extends Sprite {
     // variables declared here are called properties of the document class.
     // you have some. 
     // add your titleBannerContainer here
     var titleBannerContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

Now you can access `titleBannerContainer` from other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, I appreciate it. However after one and half day trying and searching I find some solution in the form:

```
Object(this.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1))
```

that returns me desired object titleBannerPicture call from function TitleBannerEffects().

Thank you again